# Exam question with \fbox

Tags: exam, fbox

[image]

I'm trying to replicate this format for my exam questions, but I really don't know how to do it. I tried with \fbox, but I can't put "QUESTION 2" on the box :

```
\qformat{
\fbox{\parbox{5.5in}{\centering \thequestion}}}
```

Someone know how to do this ?

Comment: Have a look ath the `tcolorbox` package. Please also clarify: should your questions be numbered atomatically and which documentclass do you use?

Comment: Yes my questions should be numbered automatically. I use \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{exam} .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As leandris mentions, you could use `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{examquestion}[1][]{colback=white, colframe=black,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily, colbacktitle=white,
enhanced,coltitle=black,top=4mm,
attach boxed title to top center={xshift=-4cm,yshift=-3mm},
title=QUESTION \thetcbcounter,#1}


\begin{document} 
\begin{examquestion}
Vrai ou faux?
\end{examquestion} 

\begin{examquestion}
Cute or duck?
\end{examquestion} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or without a frame around the inlay box:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{examquestion}[1][]{colback=white, colframe=black,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily, colbacktitle=white,
enhanced,coltitle=black,top=4mm,boxed title style={colframe=white},
attach boxed title to top center={xshift=-4cm,yshift=-3mm},
title=QUESTION \thetcbcounter,#1}


\begin{document} 
\begin{examquestion}
Vrai ou faux?
\end{examquestion} 

\begin{examquestion}
Cute or duck?
\end{examquestion} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Schrödinger's cat's previous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511221/134144) answer, here is my slightly different version with `tcolorbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{mybox}{lower separated=true,
boxrule=0.5pt,
colback=white,
colframe=black,
coltitle=black,
enhanced,
sharp corners,
halign=center,
boxed title style={colframe=white,colback=white,left=0pt,right=0pt},
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.25cm,yshift=-3.5mm},
title=\scriptsize\textsc{Question} \thetcbcounter}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
the question text
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```